# Hive - Out of Memory Exception - Java Heap Space

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am running a Hive insert on top of parquet files(created using Spark). Hive insert is using partitioned by clause. But at the end when the screen is printing messages like "Loading partition {=xyz, =123, =abc} a Java Heap Space exception is coming.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
         at java.util.HashMap.createEntry(HashMap.java:901)
         at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:888)
         at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:509)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.Partition.<init>(Partition.java:229)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.deepCopy(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1356)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getPartitionWithAuthInfo(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1003)
         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:89)
         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getPartitionWithAuthInfo(Unknown Source)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getPartition(Hive.java:1611)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getPartition(Hive.java:1565)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.StatsTask.getPartitionsList(StatsTask.java:403)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.StatsTask.aggregateStats(StatsTask.java:150)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.StatsTask.execute(StatsTask.java:117)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:153)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1508)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1275)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1093)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:916)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:906)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:359)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:456)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:466)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:748)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
```

I have set following property while running the job, and have tried to change the values to higher and lower, but every time in the end I find this error.

Properties toggled:

```
 set mapred.map.tasks=100;
 set mapred.reduce.tasks=100;
 set mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx4096m;
 set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx4096m;
 set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=100000;
 set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=100000;
```

Please suggest what is going wrong here. Hive version is 0.13.

hive-env.sh

```
 if [ "$SERVICE" = "cli" ]; then
   if [ -z "$DEBUG" ]; then
     export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -XX:NewRatio=12 -Xms12288m -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=15 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit"
   else
     export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -XX:NewRatio=12 -Xms12288m -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=15 -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit"
   fi
 fi

# The heap size of the jvm stared by hive shell script can be controlled via:
#
export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=4096
```

Comment: Issue is here with number of dynamic partitions getting created. Currently the query is creating ~38000 partition.
To make the things work we have removed a partition level, which brought the number of dynamic partitions to ~ 1400. Hence making the query to complete. But the main issue about the Memory still remains.

Answer (score 2):

It possibly related to [HIVE-10149](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10149) issue. Try to set `hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition` to `true`.