# Hive query on small dataset never finishes (or OOM)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-sandbox

Performing a simple query on a small sample dataset (195 rows, 22 columns) either throws an out of memory exception, or, following many suggestions to increase memory sizes, never ends.

**Options tried**

- [set hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition = true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38611812/1752959)
- [increase tez memory](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/12067/what-is-the-workaround-when-getting-hive-outofmemo.html)
- [increase memory & decrease shuffle size](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/35403/hive-query-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space.html)
- [increase memory](https://documentation.altiscale.com/heapsize-for-mappers-and-reducers)
- [more like that](https://community.hortonworks.com/answers/6012/view.html)

Sometimes the OOM error is gone, but then it runs for hours without any result...

**Query**

```
select * lag(status, 1, null) over (partition by type_id order by time) as status_prev from sample_table
```

**Example query that never stops**

```
 hive -hiveconf hive.tez.container.size=2048 -hiveconf hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx1640m -hiveconf tez.runtime.io.sort.mb=820 -hiveconf tez.runtime.unordered.output.buffer.size-mb=205 -e "select * lag(status, 1, null) over (partition by type_id order by time) as status_prev from sample_table"
```

**Out of memory**

```
Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1473144435077_0015)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1                 FAILED      1          0        0        1       4       0
Reducer 2             KILLED      1          0        0        1       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 00/02  [>>--------------------------] 0%    ELAPSED TIME: 18.30 s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1473144435077_0015_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1473144435077_0015_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:344)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:172)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:172)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:331)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.PipelinedSorter.<init>(PipelinedSorter.java:172)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.sort.impl.PipelinedSorter.<init>(PipelinedSorter.java:116)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.start(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
        ... 14 more
```

**Never stops**
(33 secs is example, doesnt stop in hours)

```
Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1473144435077_0025)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1                 INITED      1          0        0        1       0       0
Reducer 2             INITED      1          0        0        1       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 00/02  [>>--------------------------] 0%    ELAPSED TIME: 33.32 s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me too long to find the answer, hopefully this will help someone else...

So this breaks down to 2 problems:

1. Heap size too small, solved by increasing heap size
2. Hive job stuck in pending status

The following command solved my issues

```
hive -hiveconf hive.tez.container.size=512 -hiveconf hive.tez.java.opts="-server -Xmx512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" -e "select * lag(status, 1, null) over (partition by type_id order by time) as status_prev from sample_table"
```

[Source](https://community.hortonworks.com/answers/11431/view.html)